# Programmatically (SH Script) check which server is traffic routed/up too by HA Proxy

Tags: haproxy, high-availability, shell-scripting, healthcheck

I have 2 HA Proxy servers with Keepalived configured with them, and have 2 backend servers to which traffic is routed by HA Proxy, am writing a shell script that will sync a directory between backend servers based on which server is currently set as active using osync (I dont want activity status about the HA Proxy servers but the backend servers) (HA is configured as Active-Passive, switches to available server when current one goes down). The problem is I cannot find any resource or way that could programmatically tell me which server is currently actively accepting traffic.

Comment: I think you can get it through keepalived log itself or you can write endpoint to show you active ip.

Comment: @asktyagi can you elaborate a  bit more ?

Answer (score 0):

I recently resumed work on this after a break and successfully completed it.

**Haproxy File Configuration**

To achieve this, we first need to enable the stats socket level logs in haproxy by specifying these configurations in the haproxy config file in the global section. Refer to this guide, [HAProxy Stats Socket](https://statuslist.app/uptime-monitoring/haproxy/haproxy-stats-socket-guide/), to learn more about the stats socket.

```
global

 log /dev/log local0

 log /dev/log local1 notice

 stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/haproxy.sock mode 600 level admin

 stats timeout 2m
```

Ensure there are no policies hindering haproxy from accessing logs from the socket, such as selinux. Note that the haproxy.sock file might be located at a different path in some cases, so you may need to investigate.

**Shell Script**

Now, onto the exciting part. With stats sockets enabled, you can query haproxy to display the current stats of the operation it's performing, including all server and traffic stats.

You can view it using this command:

```
echo "show stat" | socat /var/run/haproxy.sock stdio
```

or

```
echo "show info" | socat /var/run/haproxy.sock stdio
```

Make sure to adjust the path of haproxy.sock according to your directory. Both commands yield different outputs, but for our purposes, we'll focus on the 'show stat' command.

**Output of 'Show Stat':**

```
pxname,svname,qcur,qmax,scur,smax,slim,stot,bin,bout,dreq,dresp,ereq,econ,eresp,wretr,wredis,status,weight,act,bck,chkfail,chkdown,lastchg,downtime,qlimit,pid,iid,sid,throttle,lbtot,tracked,type,rate,rate_lim,rate_max,check_status,check_code,check_duration,hrsp_1xx,hrsp_2xx,hrsp_3xx,hrsp_4xx,hrsp_5xx,hrsp_other,hanafail,req_rate,req_rate_max,req_tot,cli_abrt,srv_abrt,comp_in,comp_out,comp_byp,comp_rsp,lastsess,last_chk,last_agt,qtime,ctime,rtime,ttime,agent_status,agent_code,agent_duration,check_desc,agent_desc,check_rise,check_fall,check_health,agent_rise,agent_fall,agent_health,addr,cookie,mode,algo,conn_rate,conn_rate_max,conn_tot,intercepted,dcon,dses,

stats,FRONTEND,,,2,2,2000,85,1262591,48945969,0,0,82,,,,,OPEN,,,,,,,,,1,2,0,,,,0,0,0,2,,,,0,2079,0,82,0,0,,0,3,2161,,,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,http,,0,2,85,2079,0,0,
stats,BACKEND,0,0,0,0,200,0,1262591,48945969,0,0,,0,0,0,0,UP,0,0,0,,0,5391,,,1,2,0,,0,,1,0,,0,,,,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,,,0,0,0,2676,,,,,,,,,,,,,,http,roundrobin,,,,,,,
8080,FRONTEND,,,0,6,2000,14,426300,927680,0,0,0,,,,,OPEN,,,,,,,,,1,3,0,,,,0,0,0,3,,,,,,,,,,,0,0,0,,,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,tcp,,0,3,14,,0,0,
8082,FRONTEND,,,0,0,2000,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,OPEN,,,,,,,,,1,4,0,,,,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,0,0,0,,,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,tcp,,0,0,0,,0,0,
8080,primary_8080,0,0,0,0,,0,0,0,,0,,0,0,0,0,UP,1,1,0,7,3,2667,2578,,1,5,1,,0,,2,0,,0,L4OK,,0,,,,,,,,,,,0,0,,,,,-1,,,0,0,0,0,,,,Layer4 check passed,,2,3,4,,,,192.168.1.206:8080,,tcp,,,,,,,,
8080,backup_8080,0,0,0,6,,14,426300,927680,,0,,0,0,0,0,UP,1,0,1,0,0,5391,0,,1,5,2,,14,,2,0,,3,L4OK,,0,,,,,,,,,,,0,0,,,,,3770,,,0,0,0,6336,,,,Layer4 check passed,,2,3,4,,,,192.168.1.211:8080,,tcp,,,,,,,,
8080,BACKEND,0,0,0,6,200,14,426300,927680,0,0,,0,0,0,0,UP,1,1,1,,0,5391,0,,1,5,0,,14,,1,0,,3,,,,,,,,,,,,,,0,0,0,0,0,0,3770,,,0,0,0,6336,,,,,,,,,,,,,,tcp,roundrobin,,,,,,,
8082,primary_8082,0,0,0,0,,0,0,0,,0,,0,0,0,0,UP,1,1,0,2,0,5391,0,,1,6,1,,0,,2,0,,0,L4OK,,0,,,,,,,,,,,0,0,,,,,-1,,,0,0,0,0,,,,Layer4 check passed,,2,3,4,,,,192.168.1.206:8082,,tcp,,,,,,,,
8082,backup_8082,0,0,0,0,,0,0,0,,0,,0,0,0,0,UP,1,0,1,0,0,5391,0,,1,6,2,,0,,2,0,,0,L4OK,,0,,,,,,,,,,,0,0,,,,,-1,,,0,0,0,0,,,,Layer4 check passed,,2,3,4,,,,192.168.1.211:8082,,tcp,,,,,,,,
8082,BACKEND,0,0,0,0,200,0,0,0,0,0,,0,0,0,0,UP,1,1,1,,0,5391,0,,1,6,0,,0,,1,0,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,,,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,tcp,roundrobin,,,,,,,
```

In this output, you can see the names of the servers that have been set. For each particular server, it has its own set of stats. Towards the end of the information for a particular server, you'll find the words 'up' or 'down'. This is the piece of information that we need.

**Script to fetch Required Details**

```
RESPONSE=$(echo "show stat" | socat unix-connect:$SOCKET stdio)

PRIMARY_8080_STATUS=$(echo "$RESPONSE" | awk -F',' '/primary_8080/ {print $18}')
PRIMARY_8082_STATUS=$(echo "$RESPONSE" | awk -F',' '/primary_8082/ {print $18}')

if [ "$PRIMARY_8080_STATUS" == "UP" ] && [ "$PRIMARY_8082_STATUS" == "UP" ]; then
    echo "All Traffic is currently routed to Primary Orchestrator" 
fi
```

**Conclusion**

And that is how we programmatically retrieve information about which server is up or down. There are countless possibility here, it all comes down to how much you want to play with it.